# Bullets disappeared from presentations in LibreOffice, might be a font issue?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, fonts, openoffice.org, presentation

I have on my disk quite a lot of old presentations from earlier versions of OpenOffice (.odp format) and even StarOffice (.sxi format). When viewed in OpenOffice on my old computer (OpenOffice 3.2.0, Ubuntu 10.04), they have nice bullets as in the following screenshot:

[image: slide from OpenOffice 3.2.0/Ubuntu 10.04]

However, when viewed with recent LibreOffice (6.4.4.2) on Ubuntu 20.04, all these bullets disappeared and there are just paragaraphs of text one under the other, with first line of the paragraph usually being "outdented", as you can see below:

[image: slide from LibreOffice 6.4.4.2/Ubuntu 20.04]

I asked a question on LibreOffice forum and someone told me this may be a font issue. That person told me to check bullet character in Format -> Bullets and Numbering... menu option, but everything seems correct there. However, this might actually be a font issue, as the set of fonts installed by default on 10.04 is different than the one on 20.04 and LO may pick up the wrong font for these bullets.

But I don't know what exactly to look for. I can try to copy the 10.04 fonts that are missing in 20.04 and install them one by one to see if it helps, but this is in my opinion quite a desperate method and I don't know if it helps at all. Can anybody point me to some method to debug the issue?

Or maybe someone had experienced this issue already and knows the solution?

Some additional info: when I create a new presentation from scratch, not load an old one, bullets are displayed correctly.
Also when I switch to template view in the loaded old presentation, the bullets are visible on the slide template, but they aren't on actual slides.

Comment: It seems to me that since you're opening up files that are a decade old that there have been changes to the way that the software saves the formatting to file. This is why there's no problem when you create a new doc or update one of the old ones. Software changes over time and these are decades old files.  You probably will need to update them.

Comment: See what font is used on the newly created presentations, and change an old presentation's font to that .  Any bullets show up? Change to numbers, then back to bullets,..etc.